# Fetch record from MySQL Table based on comma seperated value in column

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have fetching record from table named `Pizza_Table`.

`Pizza_table` Schema

```
id | pizza name | pizza_topping_ids
1  | pizza1     |1,2,3
2  | pizza2     |2,3
3  | pizza3     |4,5,6
```

Actually my functionality is searching pizza based on `pizza_topping_ids`
I have work allot in this searching. but I can't find proper solution. .

I can't use `IN` clause for fetching record.

I have tried out :

1)

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM `pizza_table` 
 WHERE `pizza_topping_id` REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]'
```

Problem : fetch all record having value `2`

2)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `pizza_table` 
WHERE `pizza_topping_id` REGEXP '[[:<:]]1,2,3,4[[:>:]]'
```

but MySQL returned an empty result set,

If comma separated values are not match to any record then return result which is most having value in `topping_id` column.

EX: If i have run above query for find out pizza having 1,2,3,4 topping_id, but In database no pizza exist having such topping_id combination then result will be most covered id should be displayed like 'pizza1' having `pizza_topping_id 1,2,3`.

Sorry for bad English as well as format, but try to understand my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Please help me.

Comment: it's a bad design, in most cases but not all (*not sure*), to store comma separated values in a column. Normalize it. Create a M-to-M relationship on table pizza and toppings.

Comment: Actually i have create one separate table for topping_relation but also there is need to one-to-many relationship. otherwise how it possible?

Comment: what exactly are your tables? maybe i can help it modify `:D`

Comment: Mainly 

1) Pizza : pizza data id, name, price, etc
2) topping: id,name,description, etc.
3) pizza_topping : id, pizza_id, topping_ids(multiple_topping_ids separated by comma).

N my problem is i want to search pizza based on multiple topping_ids, if topping_id combination is not found then return pizza record having maximum covered topping_ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this-

```
SELECT * FROM `pizza_table` WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(2,pizza_topping_id)
```

OR REGEXP

```
SELECT * FROM `pizza_table` WHERE pizza_topping_id REGEXP '^2,|,2$|,2,' OR pizza_topping_id =2
```

Please see the demo : [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12801f/3)

Comment: but If i have multiple topping_ids it's works? sorry for silly question. How it works for multiple set of values like 1,2,3,4??

Comment: @Rajnish: please see the demo link

Comment: But demo is about find record using single value i want something more.. 

If i have fetching record using one value then my preference is regular expression. ok? please give me solution about multiple values in where condition.

Answer (score 2):

RegEx is slow on very big data sets.

MySQL has a [`FIND_IN_SET(value, column)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

Answer (score 2):

This may not answer your question directly but just only a suggestion `:D`

First, the rows on table `pizza_topping` doesn't need to have values separated as commas. It's hard to search for values like this using the current design. The values should be stored in rows not in column.

Consider this following schema,

```
CREATE TABLE PIZZA 
(
    PizzaID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    PRICE DECIMAL(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO PIZZA VALUES (1,'Sunny Side Up Pizza', 120);
INSERT INTO PIZZA VALUES (2,'BBQ Chicken Pizza', 200);
INSERT INTO PIZZA VALUES (3,'Muffuletta Pizza', 175);
INSERT INTO PIZZA VALUES (4,'Caramelized Onion Pizza', 135);
INSERT INTO PIZZA VALUES (5,'Broccoli Deep Dish Pizza', 150);

CREATE TABLE TOPPINGS 
(
    ToppingID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO TOPPINGS VALUES (1,'Pepperoni');
INSERT INTO TOPPINGS VALUES (2,'Mushroom');
INSERT INTO TOPPINGS VALUES (3,'Sausage');
INSERT INTO TOPPINGS VALUES (4,'Cheese');
INSERT INTO TOPPINGS VALUES (5,'Garlic');
INSERT INTO TOPPINGS VALUES (6,'Ham');
INSERT INTO TOPPINGS VALUES (7,'Tomato Sauce');
```

And the the records for `PIZZA_TOPPING` should have multiple rows of `ToppingID` for each `PizzaID`.

```
CREATE TABLE PIZZA_TOPPINGS
(
    PizzaID INT,
    ToppingID INT,
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (PizzaID)
        REFERENCES Pizza(PizzaID),
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (ToppingID)
        REFERENCES TOPPINGS(ToppingID),
    CONSTRAINT tb_UQ UNIQUE (PizzaID, ToppingID)
);

INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (2,4);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (2,5);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (2,6);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (2,7);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (3,1);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (3,5);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (4,2);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (5,1);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (6,7);
INSERT INTO PIZZA_TOPPINGS VALUES (6,1);
```

The technique of searching records like this is called [**Relational Division**](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

For example, you want to search for pizza's that have ingredients of: `Pepperoni`, `Mushroom`, `Sausage`.

```
SELECT  a.PIZZAID, a.NAME, a.PRICE
FROM    Pizza a
        INNER JOIN Pizza_Toppings b
            ON a.PizzaID = b.PizzaID
        INNER JOIN Toppings c
            ON b.ToppingID = c.ToppingID
WHERE   c.Name IN ('Pepperoni', 'Mushroom', 'Sausage')
GROUP   BY a.PIZZAID, a.NAME, a.PRICE
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4e19/1)

or pizza's that constains of atleast: `Pepperoni`, `Mushroom`,

```
SELECT  a.PIZZAID, a.NAME, a.PRICE
FROM    Pizza a
        INNER JOIN Pizza_Toppings b
            ON a.PizzaID = b.PizzaID
        INNER JOIN Toppings c
            ON b.ToppingID = c.ToppingID
WHERE   c.Name IN ('Pepperoni', 'Mushroom')
GROUP   BY a.PIZZAID, a.NAME, a.PRICE
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4e19/3)

Theses are much better than using any other functions like `FIND_IN_SET`, `REGEXP`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try find_in_set of mysql useful in this kind of structures

```
$id = 2;
$query = $this->db->query("
                         SELECT * 
                         FROM `pizza_table` 
                         WHERE FIND_IN_SET($id,pizza_topping_id)";
return $query->result();
```