# Searching on a comma separated mysql column

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

I am working on a project that was started with someone else. In the db instead for using a separate table the developer had opted for saving the `1 to many` relationships on a single table with comma separated tables. The table structure is like this

```
CREATE TABLE pages(
  pageid INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  newsid INT(6),
  pages  VARCHAR(30)
);
```

How can I search for a value `1` from the column `pages`. I have identified a few conditions that may appear, but was not been able to create a solution for it.

If I am searching for `1` the following patterns should be handles

```
1,  match
11  shouldn't match
11, shouldn't match
,1, match
,1  match
1   match
21  shouldn't match
21, shouldn't match
```

I have been thinking about this for sometime, but no solution came up. I don't think normal `%LIKE%` can be used here

Sample sql on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e87e/2)

Also I need to search multiple values too like `1`, `7` and `3`

Comment: And this is why databases should be normalized to begin with.. this problem comes up far too often.

Comment: Try [normalizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308669/reverse-group-concat-in-mysql) your database. It will be worth the effort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL search in comma list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458703/mysql-search-in-comma-list)

Comment: Comes up a good bit.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674011/mysql-check-if-numbers-are-in-a-comma-separated-list?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458703/mysql-search-in-comma-list , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401892/fetch-record-from-mysql-table-based-on-comma-seperated-value-in-column?rq=1

Comment: @user2864740 I was also wondering of why would he had done it.. Also I think I need to improve my searching techniques.. anyway thanks for the effort

Comment: @livestrong Because of improper database normalization (this fails 1NF); as a result of what specific reasoning I know not. It appears 'easier' at first but in most cases - and especially when the value is *not* opaque (eg. it is searched, joined on, or piece-wise updated) - it just doesn't fit the SQL model.

Comment: @user2864740 I n postgres there is a datatype `json` which can store data in json format and its very easy to search and index.. is there anything like that in mysql

Comment: No. While PgSQL has a JSON type and SQL Server supports an XML type which *do* support indexing/searching these still fall outside the primary RA model. As such, while useful and powerful and flexible, they should not replace primary normalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 
[`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', pages)
```

**From the documentation:**

> **FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)**
>
> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings. **A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters**. If the first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic. **Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string**. Returns NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.

*(highlighting added)*

Comment: Note: While this is the appropriate way to handle the existing structure, FIND_IN_SET cannot use indices.

Comment: also for searching multiple values this would ne enough `FIND_IN_SET('1', pages) AND FIND_IN_SET('7', pages)`... right? I have tried it and its working correctly, but not sure if it will break at some point

Comment: this would find all rows where `pages` contains '1' and '7', yes.

Comment: Fix the data. Forget the patch fcn